# Android Studio Project Build Output Error: Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: java, android, gradle, documentation

Build Output Details:

Task :app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\userName.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ee0550e8848c5279ef1306690d07508f\transformed\fragment-1.3.6\res\values\values.xml:2:4:>item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

**Failed to compile values file.**

**values.xml Original file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
<item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
<item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
<declare-styleable name="Fragment">
    <attr name="android:name"/>
    <attr name="android:id"/>
    <attr name="android:tag"/>
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="FragmentContainerView">
    <attr name="android:name"/>
    <attr name="android:tag"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I get the same error when I do following changes in values.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write items directly under sources here. I prepared an example for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="your_array_list_name">
        <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
        <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
        <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks , but I got the item tag empty in ids.xml, and got the error removed, Of course, the the error has shifted somewhere else:

Comment: This error is stubborn, as editing AndroidManifest.xml under "build"  is not allowed, what should I do:ERROR:C:\Users\userName\AndroidStudioProjects\MyLearningApp\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:12: AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute allowBackup (attr) boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is recently generated `ids.xml` file under the following directory:

> app/src/main/res/values

Deleting the file rectified the error.